# Angular js factory does not return anything with a 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am building a little project that lets the user keep a list of artists and albums and I needed a typeahead / autocomplete that would match on such things. I took inspiration from the last.fm typeahead.

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths ng-scope" ng-app="ymusica"><!--<![endif]--><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>ymusica</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/main.css">
        <script src="lib/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak{display:none;}ng\:form{display:block;}</style></head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="container">
             <div ng-controller="AlbumSearch" class="album-search text-center" ng-cloak>
                 <typeahead class="typeahead" items="music" term="term" search="searchMusic(term)" select="selectMusic(item)">
                     <div class="menu" ng-cloak>
                         <h3 ng-show="hasAlbums()">Albums</h3>
                         <ul>
                             <li typeahead-item="album" ng-repeat="album in albums" class="results">
                                 <img ng-src="{{imageSource(album)}}"><p class="name">{{album.name}}</p><p class="artist">{{album.artist}}</p>
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                         <h3 ng-show="hasArtists()">Artists</h3>
                         <ul>
                             <li typeahead-item="artist" ng-repeat="artist in artists" class="results">
                                 <img ng-src="{{imageSource(artist)}}"><p class="name">{{artist.name}}</p>
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                     </div>
                 </typeahead>
             </div>
         </div>

        <script src="lib/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/rx.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/rx.time.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/rx.coincidence.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/module.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/ymusica.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/controller.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/service.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/typeahead.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


      </body>
</html>
```

My controller code:

```
angular.module('ymusica').controller('AlbumSearch', ['$scope', 'Albums', 'Artists', '$q', function($scope, albums, artists, $q) {

$scope.albums = [];
$scope.artists = [];

var watchToObservable = function(scope, expression) {
    var observable = new Rx.Subject();

    scope.$watch(expression, observable.onNext.bind(observable));

    return observable;
}

var functionToObservable = function(scope, name) {

    var observable = new Rx.Subject();

    scope[name] = function(value) {
        observable.onNext(value);
    };

    return observable;
}

var terms = functionToObservable($scope, 'searchMusic');

terms.sample(250)
    .select(function(term) {
        var promise = $q.all([albums.query(term), artists.query(term)]);
        return Rx.promiseToObservable(promise)
    })
    .switchLatest()
    .select(function(promise) { return [promise[0].data.albums, promise[1].data.artists]; })
    .subscribe(function(result) {
        $scope.albums = result[0].slice(0, 5);
        $scope.artists = result[1].slice(0, 5);
        $scope.music = $scope.albums.concat($scope.artists);
    });

$scope.selectMusic = function(item) {
    console.log('music selected!', item);
    $scope.term = item.name;
};

$scope.imageSource = function(item) {
    return item.images['medium'];
};

$scope.hasAlbums = function() {
    return $scope.albums.length > 0;
};

$scope.hasArtists = function() {
    return $scope.artists.length > 0;
};

}]);
```

My service.js code:

```
angular.module('ymusica').factory('Albums', ['$http', function($http) {
return {
    query: function(term) {
        return $http.get('/api/album', { params: { q: term } });
    }
  };
}]);

angular.module('ymusica').factory('Artists', ['$http', function($http) {
return {
    query: function(term) {
        return $http.get('/api/artist', { params: { q:term } });
    }
  };
}]);
```

and finally

My typeahead.js code(directive):

```
angular.module('ymusica').directive('typeahead', ["$timeout",  function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><form><input ng-model="term" ng-change="query()"  type="text" autocomplete="off" /></form><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    scope: {
        search: "&",
        select: "&",
        items: "=",
        term: "="
    },
    controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.hide = false;

        this.activate = function(item) {
            $scope.active = item;
        };

        this.activateNextItem = function() {
            var index = $scope.items.indexOf($scope.active);
            this.activate($scope.items[(index + 1) % $scope.items.length]);
        };

        this.activatePreviousItem = function() {
            var index = $scope.items.indexOf($scope.active);
            this.activate($scope.items[index === 0 ? $scope.items.length - 1  : index - 1]);
        };

        this.isActive = function(item) {
            return $scope.active === item;
        };

        this.selectActive = function() {
            this.select($scope.active);
        };

        this.select = function(item) {
            $scope.hide = true;
            $scope.focused = true;
            $scope.select({item:item});
        };

        $scope.isVisible = function() {
            return !$scope.hide && ($scope.focused || $scope.mousedOver);
        };

        $scope.query = function() {
            $scope.hide = false;
            $scope.search({term:$scope.term});
        }
     }],

    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

        var $input = element.find('form > input');
        var $list = element.find('> div');

        $input.bind('focus', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() { scope.focused = true; });
        });

        $input.bind('blur', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() { scope.focused = false; });
        });

        $list.bind('mouseover', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() { scope.mousedOver = true; });
        });

        $list.bind('mouseleave', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() { scope.mousedOver = false; });
        });

        $input.bind('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 9 || e.keyCode === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function() { controller.selectActive(); });
            }

            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                scope.$apply(function() { scope.hide = true; });
            }
        });

        $input.bind('keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 9 || e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 27) {
                e.preventDefault();
            };

            if (e.keyCode === 40) {
                e.preventDefault();
                scope.$apply(function() { controller.activateNextItem(); });
            }

            if (e.keyCode === 38) {
                e.preventDefault();
                scope.$apply(function() { controller.activatePreviousItem();  });
            }
        });

        scope.$watch('items', function(items) {
            controller.activate(items.length ? items[0] : null);
        });

        scope.$watch('focused', function(focused) {
            if (focused) {
                $timeout(function() { $input.focus(); }, 0, false);
            }
        });

        scope.$watch('isVisible()', function(visible) {
            if (visible) {
                var pos = $input.position();
                var height = $input[0].offsetHeight;

                $list.css({
                    top: pos.top + height,
                    left: pos.left,
                    position: 'absolute',
                    display: 'block'
                });
            } else {
                $list.css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    }
  };
 }]);

angular.module('ymusica').directive('typeaheadItem', function() {
return {
    require: '^typeahead',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

        var item = scope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadItem);

        scope.$watch(function() { return controller.isActive(item); }, function(active) {
            if (active) {
                element.addClass('active');
            } else {
                element.removeClass('active');
            }
        });

        element.bind('mouseenter', function(e) {
            scope.$apply(function() { controller.activate(item); });
        });

        element.bind('click', function(e) {
            scope.$apply(function() { controller.select(item); });
        });
    }
 };
});
```

I am also using the last.fm api. Please help me to solve the problem. In original last.fm code is working fine but my code is return a 404 error, although the same api path are used.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to fetch the URL `/api/artist` from your own domain instead of from Last.fm's servers here:

```
return $http.get('/api/artist', { params: { q:term } })
```

<del>I _think_ it should read:

`return $http.get('https://last.fm/api/artist', { params: { q:term }});`</del>

---

The [docs](http://www.last.fm/api/intro) say that:

> The API root URL is located at http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/

Also, I do not see an end point to search for `/api/artist` with a `q` parameter, though they do have [`search` endpoints](http://www.last.fm/api/show/album.search).

Comment: now its give me this error: https://last.fm/api/album?q=ma net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: so what should i do to correct the api path and the search end point.